# How to get access to child component object in Angular

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

I have parent component `id="componentOne"` where is included another child component `<app-buttons>`:

```
<div id="componentOne">
    <app-buttons
    [component]="'WeeklyScheduleComponent'"
    [buttonTypes]="['add', 'filter']"
    [position]="'right-bottom'"
  ></app-buttons>
</div>
```

Inside component `app-buttons` there is:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.buttonUsage = new ButtonUsage(this.component, this.buttonTypes);
  }
```

So, how to get access to `this.buttonUsage` from parent component after initialization `this.buttonUsage = new ButtonUsage`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I select an element in a component template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/how-can-i-select-an-element-in-a-component-template)

Comment: With `@Output()` and `EventEmitter();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access using the **viewChild** and your component instance will be available in **ngAfterViewInit**

```
@ViewChild(AppButtonsComponent) appButtonsViewChild: AppButtonsComponent;


ngAfterViewInit() {
 console.log(this.appButtonsViewChild.buttonUsage );
}
```

if you have multiple children you can use  **@ViewChildren** decorator along side the **QueryList** generic type

```
@ViewChildren(AppButtonsComponent) appButtonsViewChildren: QueryList<AppButtonsComponent>;

ngAfterViewInit() { 
  let buttons: AppButtonsComponent[] = this.appButtonsViewChildren.toArray();
  console.log(buttons);
}
```

Comment: Since @angular 8: @ViewChild(AppButtonsComponent, {static: false}), or {static:true}, depending on when you want your component to be available at your typescript.